# Android mediaplayer not progress seeking completely

Tags: android, file, android-mediaplayer, progress, wave

Am trying to play a .wav file using media-player. Actually, I had done so far shown below. It's playing an updating the progress correctly but the problem media player is not seeking completely. Media-player stops giving out progress before the total duration of the file and stops updating progress. I have also implemented OnComplete listener also am not getting the callback. Here is my code can anyone spot me with where am missing.

```
public void playAudioFile() {
    try {

        mMediaPlayer.reset();
        setMediaPlayerSource();
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                Graphbar.setProgress(mMediaPlayer.getDuration());
            }
        });
        bPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause_selector);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Playing");
                updateProgressBar();
            }
        }).start();

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
    public void updateProgressBar() {
    Graphbar.setProgress(0);

    Graphbar.setMax(mMediaPlayer.getDuration());
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 0);
}
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        long totalDuration = Graphbar.getMax();
        long currentDuration =mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

        String TotalDur = Utilities.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration);

        tvTimeRight.setText(TotalDur);
        tvTimeLeft.setText(""+ Utilities.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

        System.out.println(currentDuration+"/"+totalDuration);
        Graphbar.setProgress((int)currentDuration); 
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1);
        }
    }
};
private void setMediaPlayerSource() {
        String audioFile = getFilename();
        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioFile);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for total duration use mediaplayer.getduration. **Remove unnecessary code from the runnable handler**  , because it will create load to ur seek bar . Because at **every second** u are calculating something and **updating layout** based on that calculation .

I would suggest you to use **chronometer** view of android.

```
public void playAudioFile() {
    try {

        mMediaPlayer.reset();
        setMediaPlayerSource();
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                Graphbar.setProgress(mMediaPlayer.getDuration());
            }
        });
        bPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause_selector);
        //set this only for once , because for one song total duration is always constant.

     updateProgressBar();
}
    public void updateProgressBar() {
    Graphbar.setProgress(0); 

    Graphbar.setMax(mMediaPlayer.getDuration());
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 0);

    long totalDuration = mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
    String TotalDur = Utilities.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration);

        tvTimeRight.setText(TotalDur);
}
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        //long totalDuration = mMediaPlayer.getDuration();=> no need of calculating total time and updating it to seekbar at every second 

        long currentDuration =mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();


        tvTimeLeft.setText(""+ Utilities.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

        System.out.println(currentDuration+"/"+totalDuration);
        Graphbar.setProgress((int)currentDuration); 
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1);
        }
    }
};
private void setMediaPlayerSource() {
        String audioFile = getFilename();
        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioFile);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```